# Bug on use of static cursor or variable

Tags: android, eclipse, findbugs

I developed an application. Then I download and run find bug tool on eclipse in my application code and I get the following bug as :

```
Bug: Write to static field 
com.abc.myapp.controllers.LoginScreenActivityController.loginDetailsCursor from instance method   
com.abc.myapp.controllers.LoginScreenActivityController.getLoginMasterData()

This instance method writes to a static field. This is tricky to get correct if multiple instances are being manipulated, and generally bad practice. 

Confidence: High, Rank: Of Concern (15)
Pattern: ST_WRITE_TO_STATIC_FROM_INSTANCE_METHOD 
Type: ST, Category: STYLE (Dodgy code)
```

My code due to which I got an error is as follows :

```
public class LoginScreenActivityController extends Activity{
    public static Cursor loginDetailsCursor;
    DatabaseHelper database_helper;
    public LoginScreenActivityController() {
    }

    public ArrayList<Login_Master> getLoginMasterData(){
        database_helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        try{
            database_helper.openDataBase();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

                /*
                *
                * **Getting **bug** here**
                *
                */
        loginDetailsCursor = database_helper.getLoginDetails();

        //Creating instance of class Login_Master model
        Login_Master login_master = new Login_Master();
        ArrayList<Login_Master> loginDetailsArrayList = new ArrayList<Login_Master>();
        if(loginDetailsCursor != null && loginDetailsCursor.getCount()>0 ){
            for(loginDetailsCursor.moveToFirst(); !loginDetailsCursor.isAfterLast(); loginDetailsCursor.moveToNext()){
                //Done Some thing .....
            }
        }else{
            //Done some thing ...
        }

        //Closing Data Base Connection.
        if (database_helper != null) 
            database_helper.close();

        return loginDetailsArrayList;       
    }

    public void updateLoginDetails(String username){
        try{
            database_helper.openDataBase();
        } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        database_helper.updateLoginTab(username);
        //Closing Data Base Connection.

                /*
                *
                *  **Getting **null check bug** here**
                *
                */
        if (database_helper != null) 
            database_helper.close();
    }   
}
```

What should I do to remove this bug. Please suggest me.

Comment: Have you tried simply by deleting the "static" keyword from the cursor declaration? In this case it's not needed to be static

Comment: @edoardotognoni I created that cursor static because i need to use the value and that cursor in other activities also.

Comment: Clear. I don't think if there is a way to clear this bug message, since your writing to a static variable inside an instance method. I suggest you to don't care about that, or else, you need to create a Service or something like that and save the cursor in that component

Comment: @edoardotognoni Thank you but can you help me out that which kind of service you mentioned and how to create it?

Comment: That's pretty simple. A service is an Android component. It's basically used for background processes and send notification(But you don't need it). When you start a service, you can "bind" to that from many component. A service, always expose a Binder (An object) that it's used to communicate to the service. So after you get that binder, you could simply save your cursor in your service and then get it from all of the others component. Check this link: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: You should *never* write to a static field from an instance method. So if the field must be static, then the code that initializes it should also be static. Also note that your code will break if you run more than 1 thread, because the threads will overwrite each other's `loginDetailsCursor`. It seems that your `loginDetailsCursor` should really be a local variable, because you are reinitializing it every time, anyway.